# Who could specifically explain the remaining 2 bytes in first sector of disk?

Tags: linux, hardware

We know the size of sector in disk is 512 bytes. We also know the first sector mainly record MBR and partition table. The size of MBR is 446 bytes and the size of partition table is 64 bytes. But the sum of the size of MBR and partition is 510 bytes isn't equal 512 bytes. What do we use the remaining 2 bytes to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last two bytes are the boot signature. The BIOS is supposed to check that these bytes have values 0x55 and then 0xAA before loading the bootstrap code from sector 0, so this isn't really a Linux question.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/149877

Comment: I add Linux tag, because I see this question in book of Linux.

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) has tables for the common layouts, and the last two bytes are used for the "boot signature" (55 AA).

The BIOS is supposed to check this before trying to launch into the booting process.